# Apache Beam - what are the limits of Deduplication function

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I've a Google dataflow pipeline, build using Apace Beam. The application receives about 50M records everyday, now to ignore duplicate records, we are planning to use the [Deduplication](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.21.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Deduplicate.html) Function provided by beam framework.

The document doesn't states the maximum input count for which the Deduplication function would work neither the maximum duration for which it can persist the data.

Would it be good design, to simply throw 50M records onto the deduplication function, out of which around half would be duplicates, and save keep the persistence duration of 7 days?

Answer (score 1):

The deduplication function, as described in the link that you provide, performs a deduplicate per window.

If you have window of 1H, and you duplicate arrive every 3H, the function don't duplicate them, because they are in different windows.

So, you can define window over 1 day, or more. There is no limit. The data are stored on the workers (to save them), and also kept in memory (for efficiency). And more you have data, stronger and bigger must be the server config to manage the quantity of data.

Comment: We don't have any windowing yet, so everything is in global window. Would it be okay to keep the duration of the deduplication for 7 days? - resources is not an problem - just concerned about efficiency when deduplication duration is 7 days and everyday there are 50M incoming records.

Comment: 1 global windows of 7 days? Therefore 350M of messages to deduplicate. It will take a while and lot of memory, but if it's your use case, it should work. I never tried on a huge amount of data like this!

Comment: Yes, thanks for the response. I will try to reiterate the design. If we reduce the deduplication persistence time to 1 day and the input messages in one day is 50M, provided enough resources, would the deduplication be affected, we are not expecting a delay in the deduplication step.

Comment: @kylebutters have you managed to reiterate the design? Was guillaume blaquiere's answer helpful? Waiting for your response.